# Passing local variable as parameter into RSpec shared_examples Always Nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a spec like this:

```
shared_examples_for 'using the id' do |the_id|
    it 'should do something with the id' do
        # do something with the_id
    end
end

id = nil
describe 'a spec' do
    it 'should retrieve id' do
        id = getId
        expect(id).to eq(12345)
    end
    include_examples 'using the id', id
end
```

The problem is that once the spec runs and enters the shared example via include_examples, the id is always nil.  I can verify that in the first it block in the spec itself that the id is being set, it seems to be the hand off that is incorrect.

I cannot use it_behaves_like as we are using rspec for journey testing, so order matters.  Every example I see says this should work, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Move the definition of `id` outside the `it` block to have access to it in the shared examples or use `getId` when you call `include_examples`, because `it` and `describe` have different scopes of execution.

```
describe 'a spec' do
  def getId
    12345
  end

  shared_examples 'using the id' do |the_id|
    it 'should do something with the id' do
      expect(id).to eq(12345)
      expect(the_id).to eq(12345)
    end
  end

  let(:id) { getId }
  it 'should retrieve id' do
    expect(id).to eq(12345)
  end

  include_examples 'using the id', getId
end
```